# htaccess code to encode URLs with different page name

Tags: .htaccess

the below htaccess code work for single URL with same page

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /current/shoppe/sub-category.php?category=$1 [L]
```

now, i need to rewrite a URL of another page.

Comment: `now, i need to rewrite a URL of another page` Ok and? What page? where are your examples?

Comment: page name is "main-categoty" and value passing is "main_id". my link is " current/shoppe/main-category.php?main_id=Bridal-Accessories"

Comment: guys i need help on this